# Can I make zsh expand tildes in double quotes?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Ever since I discovered you can use filename completion in double quotes, I've been using it for files with spaces in their names (like `/Library/Application Support`). It looks nicer and is easier to read than a path littered with backslashes. The problem is, there are also things in my home folder with spaces in their names (`~/Library/Application Support`, and I can't use quotes there because they escape tildes. Is there any way to turn that off?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think so. The `zsh` [user's guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide05.html) simply says:

> Double quotes allow some, but not all, forms of substitution inside. More specifically, they allow parameter expansion, command substitution and arithmetic substitution, but not any of the others: process substitution doesn't happen, braces and initial tildes and equals signs are not expanded and patterns are not special. Here's a table; each expression on the left is some command line argument, and the results show what is substituted if it appears outside quotes, or in double quotes.
>
> ```
> Expression      Outside quotes  In double quotes 
> ------------------------------------------------ 
> ...  
> ~/foo           /home/pws/foo   ~/foo
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Tildes don’t expand in double quotes but you don’t need them too. Place the starting quote *after* the tilde and it works as you want:

```
~"/Library/Application Support"
~/"Library/Application Support"
```

Alternatively, the environment variable `HOME` expands to the same:

```
"$HOME/Library/Application Support"
"${HOME}/Library/Application Support"
```